# A replacement for the Samsung Series 9 and Ativ Book 9 15" ultrabooks

Tags: laptop

In 2012 I've bought a Samsung Series 9 X4D ultrabook with a 15" screen. I'm still quite satisfied with this product. Currently, I am searching for an additional notebook with similar requirements. Unfortunately, Samsung has withdrawn from the European notebook market.

Focus lies on:

- haptics and workmanship
- matte screen with at least 14" and a resolution of 1600x900 or better
- SSD only
- large capacity
- touchpad and keyboard
- low weight
- round 1000€/1100$

CPU and graphics power are of lesser importance. It does not necessarily have to be labeled as an ultrabook either.

The only devices I've found so far are the Lenovo Yoga and L-Series. Are there further solutions for these requirements?

Comment: There might also be the option of buying from the US and having it shipped to Europe.

Comment: What about second-hand items? Does weight really matter that much?

Answer (score 4):

Since I recently purchased a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro (now discontinued), I want to recommend the [Lenovo Yoga 3](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/yoga-laptop-series/yoga-3-14/) (€630 and up). Although I haven't used this exact product, I've used its predecessor (the 2 Pro) that is nearly identical to it.

Physical specifications:

- Multi-gesture touchpad (scroll, zoom, swipe pages, switch windows, etc.)
- Full HD 1920x1080 multigesture touchscreen
- ~9-hour battery life (can actually last longer if you keep the brightness down)
- Backlit keyboard (Fn+Space toggles it)
- Only 1.58kg/3.5lbs – super light and easy to carry with one hand
- Screen folds all the way around (laptop, tent, and tablet modes) and the display can change orientation (perfect for reading)
- *Very* durable with amazing build quality

Tech specifications:

- Up to an Intel i7-5500U processor (2.4GHz)
- GT 940M 2GB graphics card
- Up to 256GB SSD
- 720p webcam
- Bluetooth 4.0, 802.11 A/C WiFi
- 1x USB 2.0, 2x USB 3.0, 4-in-1 card reader, audio/mic combo jack, Micro-HDMI

[image: Lenovo Yoga 3]

The Yoga 3 comes in numerous models, the best of which is only €870/$980 for all the best components. This laptop (or ultrabook, whatever you want to call it) can be used for *so many things*. Lenovo has a huge sale on the Yoga series right now with about 30% off, so I recommend looking into this soon.